# Most efficient way to lookup/find eventname and convert to string

Tags: c++, lookup

I have a huge C struct like this:

```
typedef struct  ABCEvent_t
{
      ABCEventType_t   eventType;
      union
   {
         ABCEvent1_t  greenevent;
     ABCEvent2_t  blueevent;
         etc
       }
   } u;
   char    heap[ABCPRIV_MAX_HEAP];

} ABCEvent_t;
```

There are about 150 different event types.  I need to write to a log file the event name (as a string).  The struct is in a header file I include.

What is the best way to lookup the event type and convert to string?

So I want to print eg blueevent to the log.  Or possibly ABCEvent2_t if it is easier.

I am thinking that I will need to create a lookup table of the names in my code and use the C preprocessor stringising to return a string?

Any tips would be most appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use inheritance ? The problem will almost solve itself after you add a "getEventName()" virtual method that could either return some handcrafted string or a typeid().name(). If your question is not C++ related, drop the C++ tag and use the C one.

Comment: You mean class SpecialisedEvent : public Event.  Good idea.  I am at early stages and was only tihnking about logging.  But yes idea makes sense.